# SSL Authenticated SOAP Request works in SoapUI but not through code

Tags: tls, .net

I am connecting to a SOAP webservice that requires SSL authentication. I (the web service client) have a .pfx file and provided the public certificate for that file to the company whose web service I am accessing. I am able to send a successful SOAP request to their web service through SoapUI (after configuring SoapUI to use the .pfx).

Now I am trying to send the same request through code (VB.NET) but having trouble connecting. The error message I get after invoking the request is: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

In code, I have a proxy class for the web service that inherits SoapHttpClientProtocol. The code that sets up the SSL and invokes the request is as follows:

```
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("UpdateLeadByDMS_v1", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, _
        ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare), _
        CaptureMessageExtension()>
    Public Function UpdateLeadByDMS_v1(ByVal leadPushRequest As LeadPushRequest) As LeadPushResponse
        Dim store As X509Store = Nothing
        Try
            store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
            store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly Or OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
            Const thumbprint As String = "36C82D8E7BAEEB2E9B88F4748CB60AE6E0A89F64"
            Dim certCollection As X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, False)
            If certCollection.Count > 0 Then
                Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = certCollection(0)
                Me.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
            End If
        Finally
            If store IsNot Nothing Then
                store.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
        Dim results() As Object
        Try
            results = Me.Invoke("UpdateLeadByDMS_v1", New Object() {leadPushRequest})
        Catch ex As Exception
            SendError(New Exception(ex.Message))
            Throw
        End Try

        Return CType(If(results IsNot Nothing, results(0), Nothing), LeadPushResponse)
    End Function
```

I've tracked both requests in WireShark and seen the following TLS handshake steps:

SoapUI - Works
[image: SoapUI Wireshark Capture - Works]

Code - Fails SSL authentication
[image: Code Wireshark Capture - Fails]

Does anybody have an idea of why one would succeed while the other fails? It looks to me like the code is failing during the clients authentication of the server... but I have already tried setting the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback delegate to return true and that did not change anything.

Thank you for any insight you can provide!

EDIT:
Here is the information from the last TLS packet in the network logs. It is the ServerHello and Certificate handshake parts from the server. There was no errors that I saw. 
[image: Last TLS packet]
After that there was only the following communications between the client and server:
[image: last communication between server and client]

Comment: You need to take a look inside the packet and see the specific error, then tell us the ***exact*** phrase used to describe it (or include here a snapshot of it).

Comment: @DarkLighting I edited my post to include that info. I used Microsoft Network Monitor instead of WireShark this time, which is why it looks a little different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! The SSL handshake was failing on my (client) side because the client certificate did not have the right permissions for the account that was running the web application. I was able to find this out by looking in 'Windows Event Viewer' under 'Windows Logs --> System'. There I saw an error stating: "A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL client credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 10003."

Googling that error state brought me to this forum post (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e70a8dbc-6f48-4fde-a93b-783554344822/a-fatal-error-occurred-when-attempting-to-access-the-ssl-client-credential-private-key?forum=ocscertificates) which said that it was a permissions error. Whatever account was running the application could not access the private key of the certificate. To fix this I simply gave read permission for my client certificate to the correct account through MMC in Windows. This post provides some insight on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate

Hopefully this helps someone in the future! Remember to check your permissions!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](http://forums.asp.net/post/1695893.aspx#1695893) where someone had received the same error phrase *"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."* (although i reckon this as a very generic description). It says that you need to **install the client certificate** in the **local computer store**.

Did you do that? If not, how does it work out for you?

Comment: I did have the certificate but did not have the correct permissions for the account running the web app. This worked in SoapUI because my local account was running the program. A different account was configured for the app pool in IIS. I've posted my answer. Thanks for your help!